# exiting chroot leads to getpt failure

Tags: linux, debian, process, chroot

On a Debian Jessie machine I have a rootfs image which I chroot in this way:

```
mount myimage.img /mnt/myimage
cp /usr/bin/qemu-arm-static /mnt/myimage/usr/bin/
mount --rbind /dev /mnt/myimage/dev
mount -t proc none /mnt/myimage/proc
mount -o bind /sys /myimage/sys
chroot /mnt/myimage
```

on exiting I do the opposite:

```
rm /mnt/myimage/usr/bin/qemu-arm-static
umount /mnt/myimage/sys
umount /mnt/myimage/proc
umount /mnt/myimage/dev
umount -l /mnt/myimage
```

But when I try to open a new terminal in my host machine I get the following error:

> Execution of the child process failed
>
> getpt failed: file or directory not exists (translated from Italian)

Perhaps I'm forgetting something?

Comment: I see nothing obviously wrong, though I would use the full path to `myimage.img`, because the current directory may not set when the command is executed. Are you using `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_login` for the start-up commands? I presume the commands work when you type them manually.

Comment: You're right about the absolute path, it's a development dir with both scripts sticked there, but it's better to use full path. I use those commands in a /bin/bash script, but the behavior is the same even if I type them manually.

Comment: If you type them one at a time, which command fails?

Comment: I don't see any error. But after the last umount I cannot open a new terminal in my Debian machine. I need to reboot, exiting and logging in again it's not enough.

Comment: Looking in more detail, `mount --rbind /dev /mnt/myimage/dev` will replace the `/dev` directory with whatever is in the `/dev` directory in your image: do you have all the terminal definitions there?

Comment: I have them (I guess you're talking about the tty* devices). But unmounting /mnt/myimage/dev should not restore the initial state?

Comment: Yes, it would, but if the shell doesn't start there is nothing to execute the logout commands. Do you have the usual utilities in `/bin` (including `bash`) in your `myimage.img` file system?